# React useState item seems to be empty when called even though item is set

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

So I'm trying to fetch data from a Flask API and insert it in the React table. I can get the data from the API, and I'm setting it as a list in `useState`, however, when I'm trying to access the list it seems to be empty.

Here is my Flask API route, it works fine and returns the data.

```
def get_report(productname, reportname):
    mydb = client[productname]
    mycol = mydb[reportname]
    testlist = []
    instance_list = []
    for x in mycol.find({}):
        print(x)
        testlist.append({"instance": "x["Instance"]", "source": x["Source"], "target": x["Target"], "volume": x["Volume of Interference"]})
    for instance in testlist:
        instance_list.append(instance)
    response = jsonify({"data": testlist})
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response
```

Here is my React component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useMemo} from 'react'
import { useTable } from 'react-table'
import './Report.css'

export default function Report(props){
    const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
    
    const getInstances = () => {
        let productname = props.match.params.name
        let reportname = props.match.params.reportname
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/app/reports/" + productname + "/" + reportname)
        .then(res => {
          return res.json();
        }).then(res => {
          setItem(res.data)
          console.log(res.data)
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getInstances();       
    },  []);

    const mockData = [
      {
      "instance": 1, "source": "test23", "target": "test53", "volume": "test123123"
      },
      {
        "instance": 2, "source": "test24242", "target": "test22324", "volume": "test223"
      }
    ]

    const COLUMNS =[
      {
          Header: 'Instance no.',
          accessor: 'instance'
      },
      {
          Header: 'Source Component',
          accessor: 'source'
      },
      {
          Header: 'Target Component',
          accessor: 'target'
      },
      {
          Header: 'Interference Volume',
          accessor: 'volume'
      },
    ];

    
    const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])
    
    const data = useMemo(() => item, [])

    const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns,
        data
    })

    const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow} = tableInstance

    return(
        <div className = "content">
          <table className="table"{...getTableProps()}>
            <thead>
                {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                    <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps}>
                        {headerGroup.headers.map((column) =>(
                            <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
                        ))}                       
                    </tr>        
                ))}    
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {rows.map((row) => {
                        prepareRow(row)
                        return(
                            <tr{...row.getRowProps()}>
                            {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                              <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                            ))}   
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
            </tbody>
          </table>            
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm calling the `getInstances` function when the page is reloaded and it receives the data just fine. I have console logged the returning data (`res.data` in this case) inside the `getInstances()` function and it seems to be a form of [{...},{...},{...},{...},{...} etc], same as the `mockData`.

The `mockData` renders properly in the React table but the data received from the API does not. If I try to console log the `useState` item, it seems to be an empty list and that might be the reason why it's not rendering properly, but I cannot wrap my head around why this happens. I even tried to insert the `mockData` into the `useState` item and same problem arises. Am I using the state wrong or is my data type wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the `const data = useMemo(() => item, [])`.

`useMemo` returns  a memoized value. It only recomputes the memoized value when one of the dependencies has changed. If you provide no dependencies, it only runs once. With that empty dependency array, you set `data` to an empty array set by `useState([])` on the first render before you fetch your report. You can run the code snippet below to see how it works.

Anyway, you don't need to use `useMemo` here as you only fetch the report on page load by providing an empty dependency array in the `useEffect` hook.

If you remove `const data = useMemo(() => item, []);` and use your `item` state as the data in `useTable`, your app should render the table correctly:

```js
const tableInstance = useTable({
  columns,
  data: item,
});
```

```js
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

  const getInstances = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setItems(data.slice(0, 2));
      });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getInstances();
  }, []);

  const dataWithEmptyDepArray = React.useMemo(() => items, []);
  const dataWithDepArray = React.useMemo(() => items, [items]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>
        <code>dataWithEmptyDepArray</code>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(dataWithEmptyDepArray, null, 2)}</pre>
      </p>
      <p>
        <code>dataWithDepArray</code>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(dataWithDepArray, null, 2)}</pre>
      </p>
      <p>
        <code>items</code>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(items, null, 2)}</pre>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```css
code {
  background-color: #ededed;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
}

p {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yep, that does it, now it works properly! Cant believe i spent hours on this one.